# Kendo Dataviz charts - Adding a shape as a point on a bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I've got a chart with 2 series - one is a line series, and another is a bar series.
I need to add a marker to a point on the chart as a 3rd series but can't find a way of doing it. Current code:

```
  $("#lowerDayschart").kendoChart({
                width: "200px",
                height: "190px",
                title: {
                    text: "Title"
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "bottom"
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "column"
                },
                series: [
                        {
                            name: "My Name",
                            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1],
                            gap: 0,
                            spacing: 0,
                            type: "column",
                            YAxisType: 'primary'
                        }, {
                            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1],
                            gap: 0,
                            spacing: 0,
                            type: "line",
                            markers: {
                                visible: false
                            },
                            YAxisType: 'secondary'
                        }],
                valueAxis: {
                    line: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                },
                categoryAxis: {
                    categories: ["-8", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "8"],
                    majorGridLines: {
                        visible: false
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "{0}"
                }
            });
```

Chart at the moment:

[image]

Chart as I'd like it:

[image]

Comment: Whats the problem to add one more to the series as a scatter one?
http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/scatter-charts/index.html

Comment: Hi Petur. I tried that (as well as adding a bubble chart series), but neither renders anything. Have you had this working then?